# MySQL 1136 Error when inserting values that have auto incremented and default fields

Tags: mysql

I created a MySQL database, but immediately after I am having difficulty inserting dummy data in one of the tables. This was the query I used to create the database with three tables: categories, transactions, budgets_2018;

```
use mct;
create table if not exists categories(
id int auto_increment not null,
category varchar(255),
primary key (id)
);

create table if not exists transactions(
id int auto_increment not null,
dt date,
vendor varchar(255),
amount decimal(7,2),
cat_id int default 1,
primary key(id),
foreign key(cat_id) references categories(id)
);

create table if not exists budgets_2018(
id int not null,
January decimal(7,2) default 0.00,
February decimal(7,2) default 0.00,
March decimal(7,2) default 0.00,
April decimal(7,2) default 0.00,
May decimal(7,2) default 0.00,
June decimal(7,2) default 0.00,
July decimal(7,2) default 0.00,
August decimal(7,2) default 0.00,
September decimal(7,2) default 0.00,
October decimal(7,2) default 0.00,
November decimal(7,2) default 0.00,
December decimal(7,2) default 0.00,
primary key(id),
foreign key(id) references categories(id)
);
insert into categories (category) values ('Uncategorized');
insert into budgets_2018(id) values ((select id from categories where category = 'Uncategorized'));
```

Categories has a one to many relationship with transactions and a one to one with budgets_2018, in theory. Also the last lines of code do produce a category table with one record (1, 'Uncategorized') as well a budgets_2018 table with one record (1, 0.00, 0.00...x11 more for each month).

And this was the query I used to add some dummy data into the transactions table. The tables has five columns, the first being auto incremented and the fifth defaults to 1. The fifth column (cat_id) is also a foreign key to the primary of categories Thus I left them out of the insert query below:

```
insert into transactions (dt, vendor, amount) values (
(curdate(), 'DummyVendor1', 3.45),
(curdate(), 'DummyVendor2', 11.47),
(curdate(), 'DummyVendor3', 73.22),
(curdate(), 'DummyVendor4', 199.27),
(curdate(), 'DummyVendor5', 34.56),
(curdate(), 'DummyVendor6', 18.99),
(curdate(), 'DummyVendor7', 1.45),
(curdate(), 'DummyVendor8', 2.41)
);
```

However after the insert query I keep getting

> "Error 1136: Column count doesnt match value count at row 1".

Correctly me if I'm wrong but column one of transactions (id auto incremented) and column five (cat_id defaulted to 1) should populate without my need for an explicit insert, correct? So I'm not sure what's causing the error.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your first and last parenthesis. Remove them, and it should insert fine:

```
insert into transactions (dt, vendor, amount) values 
    (curdate(), 'DummyVendor1', 3.45),
    (curdate(), 'DummyVendor2', 11.47),
    (curdate(), 'DummyVendor3', 73.22),
    (curdate(), 'DummyVendor4', 199.27),
    (curdate(), 'DummyVendor5', 34.56),
    (curdate(), 'DummyVendor6', 18.99),
    (curdate(), 'DummyVendor7', 1.45),
    (curdate(), 'DummyVendor8', 2.41);
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you